# Need help accessing second layer of data in an API call in Swift 2

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api

I am using the following line of code to access "intent", but I need to access the "Value" within "from" (e.g. london). What am I doing wrong?

My original code:

```
func witDidGraspIntent(outcomes: [AnyObject]!, messageId: String!, customData: AnyObject!, error e: NSError!) {
    if ((e) != nil) {
        print("\(e.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    let outcomes : NSArray = outcomes!
    let firstOutcome : NSDictionary = outcomes.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
    let intent : String = firstOutcome.objectForKey("intent")as! String
    let query : String = firstOutcome.objectForKey("from":["value"])as! String
```

The API data structure is as follows:

```
{
"_text" = "show me flights from london to turkey";
confidence = "0.536";
entities =     {
    from =         (
                    {
            suggested = 1;
            type = value;
            value = london;
        }
    );
    productCategory =         (
                    {
            type = value;
            value = flights;
        }
    );
    to =         (
                    {
            suggested = 1;
            type = value;
            value = turkey;
        }
    );
};
intent = flightSearch;
metadata = "";
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You forgot to refer to `entities` (`from` is inside `entities`).

Comment: thanks Eric, but how would I write the code to access 3 layers in? I tried ("entities":["from"]:["value"]) but it is kicking back errors. really appreciate the help

Comment: Is this supposed to be JSON or a Property List? It's flagged as JSON but it looks like an older OpenStep-type plist.

Comment: @KennethBruno it is json pulled from wit.ai and stored in an array. I need to be able to split out the 2nd and 3rd layers of content. Any ideas?

Comment: Well the structure you posted is not JSON, it appears to be a `NSDictionary` that has been printed with `print()`. The representation follows the format of an older ASCII plist.

Comment: Why not just use Swift subscripts? `entities["from"]["value"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you'd pull values out of a `NSDictionary` using [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1)

```
import Foundation

let outcomeData = "{ \"_text\" = \"show me flights from london to turkey\"; confidence = \"0.536\"; entities = { from = ( { suggested = 1; type = value; value = london; } ); productCategory = ( { type = value; value = flights; } ); to = ( { suggested = 1; type = value; value = turkey; } ); }; intent = flightSearch; metadata = \"\"; }".propertyList()

// Safely cast as NSDictionary
if let outcome = outcomeData as? NSDictionary {
  // Safely get the value from a key and cast as String
  if let intent = outcome.valueForKey("intent") as? String {
    print(intent) // => "flightSearch"
  }
  // Safely get the value from a key path and cast as a String
  if let query = outcome.valueForKeyPath("entities.from.value.@firstObject") as? String{
    print(query) // => "london"
  }
}
```

Avoid explicitly-unwrapped `Optional` and forced unwrapping of `Optional` wherever possible. You're asking for lots of trouble down the line using them.

Comment: thanks @kenneth that has done the trick. Really appreciate the support.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves the problem. Glad to help.